# How to get the eigenstates of angular momentum of the radiation field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, polarization

it is given the angular momentum with $J = \int x \wedge(E \wedge B) dx $. Therefore I get the operator $J = \sum_k (x \wedge k) N_{k,\lambda} $ where $N_{k,\lambda} $ is the number operator, $k$ is the momentum and $\lambda $ is the polarization of the photon.

Now I have to consider the component of $J$ in the direction of propagation, i.e. the projection $J \cdot \hat{k}$ where $\hat{k}$ denotes the normalized vector.

But what does $J \cdot \hat{k}  $ mean? I'm confused, because in my opinion the product is an inner product and my solution would be zero. How can I determine the eigenstate of $J \cdot \hat{k}$ ?

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: Possibly [useful](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0504082).

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: [Review WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_of_light).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this definition of J leads to J=0 for a plane wave, even for a circularly polarised one. The latter case is a paradox since photons have spin angular momentum, as confirmed by experiment by R.A. Beth in 1935.